# Training uNet model the prediction is only black

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, training-data

I'm training a uNet model for segmentation. After training the model, the output is all zeros and I can't understand why.

I saw recommendations that I should be using a specific loss function, so I used a dice loss function. This because the black area (0) is way bigger then white area (1).

Am I doing something wrong?

My **model** is:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 80, 80, 1)    0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 80, 80, 64)   640         input_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 80, 80, 64)   36928       conv2d_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 40, 40, 64)   0           conv2d_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 40, 40, 128)  73856       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 40, 40, 128)  147584      conv2d_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 20, 20, 128)  0           conv2d_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 20, 20, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 20, 20, 256)  590080      conv2d_5[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 10, 10, 256)  0           conv2d_6[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 10, 10, 512)  1180160     max_pooling2d_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 10, 10, 512)  2359808     conv2d_7[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 10, 10, 512)  0           conv2d_8[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 5, 5, 512)    0           dropout_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 5, 5, 1024)   4719616     max_pooling2d_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 5, 5, 1024)   9438208     conv2d_9[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 5, 5, 1024)   0           conv2d_10[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTrans (None, 10, 10, 512)  2097664     dropout_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 10, 10, 1024) 0           dropout_1[0][0]
                                                                 conv2d_transpose_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 10, 10, 512)  4719104     concatenate_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 10, 10, 512)  2359808     conv2d_11[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTrans (None, 20, 20, 256)  524544      conv2d_12[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 20, 20, 512)  0           conv2d_6[0][0]
                                                                 conv2d_transpose_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 20, 20, 256)  1179904     concatenate_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, 20, 20, 256)  590080      conv2d_13[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTrans (None, 40, 40, 128)  131200      conv2d_14[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 40, 40, 256)  0           conv2d_4[0][0]
                                                                 conv2d_transpose_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)              (None, 40, 40, 128)  295040      concatenate_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 40, 40, 128)  147584      conv2d_15[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DTrans (None, 80, 80, 64)   32832       conv2d_16[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_4 (Concatenate)     (None, 80, 80, 128)  0           conv2d_2[0][0]
                                                                 conv2d_transpose_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)              (None, 80, 80, 64)   73792       concatenate_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)              (None, 80, 80, 64)   36928       conv2d_17[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_19 (Conv2D)              (None, 80, 80, 2)    1154        conv2d_18[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_20 (Conv2D)              (None, 80, 80, 1)    3           conv2d_19[0][0]
==================================================================================================
```

**Loss Function**

```py
def dice_loss_v2(y_true, y_pred):
    numerator = 2 * tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=(1,2,3))
    denominator = tf.reduce_sum(y_true + y_pred, axis=(1,2,3))

    return 1 - numerator / denominator
```

**Activation**

```py
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=dice_loss_v2,
                  metrics=['accuracy', iou_loss_core])
```

Predefined Learning Rate is LR=0.001

An extra information:

```py
        datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                    rotation_range=10, 
                    width_shift_range=0.1, 
                    height_shift_range=0.1, 
                    zoom_range=0.1)
        datagen.fit(X_train)

        model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=100), steps_per_epoch=len(X_train), 
                                        epochs=4, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: one of the possible reason could be your mask. May be you are treating background as a target object from the mask.  This is why it's learning to detect background that is 0(black).
Check your mask. I faced the same problem then I checked my mask.

Comment: I'm guessing not. You can see in this [image](https://prnt.sc/qi8hw1) that in the top there is the input, the second the mask for that input, and the prediction was like that...

Comment: can you show me your X_train single element value and Y_train single element value?

Comment: I'm doing a cross-validation since that dataset has only 1600 images. I divided into 4 folds based on a parameter called texture (not important). So I trained and got the all black predictions. I also tried to overfit completely the model by training only one image. The loss function remains the same after three epochs and the output is all black again.

Comment: If there is nothing in the preprocessing step and if it's because of overfitting then I will suggest you to use albumentation module for data augmentation

Comment: You can use this : https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models

Comment: I had the same problem back region were more than white region. My model was not yielding good result . classifying and label all pixel as 0
(black). Using some of the advanced augmentation techniques and pretrained model I was able to improve my results.

Comment: I don't think it's overfit, if I'm training the same image that I'm testing it should bring results, that's why I thought the problem was in the model or on the loss function.
You said X_train and y_train, do you want me to send the numpy arrays? They are (n,80,80,1) and the mask is the same. 
I will try to see those segmentation_models and see what I can use

Comment: To improve the result you can go for the following things: 1)Use albumentation for data augmentation 2) create your own custom dataset and add preprocessing(standardising/normalising image) to faster the convergence. 
3) Use focal loss for this background-foreground imbalance.
4) Use Pretrained encoder.

Comment: Revert back if the above following thing still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will try to use focal loss (or even join both loss functions) and perhaps use a pretrained encoder!

Comment: I think you are augmenting your inputs but not your masks, [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3059) might help

Comment: Oh that's true! I will check. Because what I did that help me "solve" the problem was removing the data augmenting. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The mask may be all black because of the pixels predicting as 0 and 1. As 0 and 1 both are nearly black in color space (0,255). So, Multiply mask by 255 and then try to save/show it (All 1's are converted to 255). You will get required output.